# Connection error

Tags: json-rpc, connection

i have installed bitcoin node, it was syncing before i went to sleep, i want to know the percentage of the synced,  anytime i query on the bitcoin-cli getblockcount ,i get this error "
error: timeout on transient error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:18332

Make sure the bitcoind server is running and that you are connecting to the correct RPC port.
" but  this is what i have in my bitcoin.conf file "rpcport=18332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
" would appreciate help

Comment: Is your `bitcoind` running? Is it on testnet?

Comment: it keeps saying this when i tried to run bitcoind "Error: Cannot obtain a lock on data directory /root/.bitcoin. Bitcoin Core is probably already running."